# ListView.builder error : [object was given an infinite size during layout], [BoxConstraints forces an infinite width]

Tags: flutter, listview

I'm new to flutter and making an app that can write lines on the `WorkbookDrawingPage` Widget and under the `WorkbookDrawingPage` widget, `pdfviewer` widget is placed by using a `stack`.

So, I want to make `WorkbookDrawingPage` as a `ListView` and when the user scroll horizontally or clicks the next page button, the next page of `WorkbookDrawingPage` widget shows and `WorkbookDrawingPage` widget is fit wtih the screen

I wrapped the `sfPdfViewer` widget and `WorkbookDrawingPage` with a `InteractiveViewer` so it can zoom and pan both

but when I use `ListView.Builder` widget, errors occur.

like this

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderCustomPaint's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
  RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2418:11)
The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, h=1374.2)
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Container Container:file:///C:/Users/park/AndroidStudioProjects/firebase_img_writing_test/lib/screen/workbook_view_page.dart:111:24

he following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#2a0e8 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView ListView:file:///C:/Users/park/AndroidStudioProjects/firebase_img_writing_test/lib/screen/workbook_view_page.dart:107:24

The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
RenderIndexedSemantics object was given an infinite size during layout.

This probably means that it is a render object that tries to be as big as possible, but it was put inside another render object that allows its children to pick their own size.
The nearest ancestor providing an unbounded width constraint is: RenderIndexedSemantics#359f9 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
...  needs compositing
...  parentData: index=0; layoutOffset=0.0 (can use size)
...  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=1374.2)
...  size: Size(Infinity, 1374.2)
...  index: 0
The constraints that applied to the RenderIndexedSemantics were: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=1374.2)
The exact size it was given was: Size(Infinity, 1374.2)

See https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/box-constraints for more information.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  ListView ListView:file:///C:/Users/park/AndroidStudioProjects/firebase_img_writing_test/lib/screen/workbook_view_page.dart:107:24
```

When I removed the `InteractiveViewer`, It shows same error.

Here's my code

> WorkbookViewPage.dart

```
class WorkbookViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String downloadedURL;
  String workbookName;

  WorkbookViewPage(this.downloadedURL, this.workbookName, {super.key});

  @override
  State<WorkbookViewPage> createState() => _WorkbookViewPageState();
}

class _WorkbookViewPageState extends State<WorkbookViewPage> {
  final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();
  late PdfViewerController _pdfViewerController;
  int _lastClosedPage = 1;

  bool _memoMode = false;

  // Widget Key
  GlobalKey _viewKey = GlobalKey();

  // pen size control widget Entry
  bool isOverlayVisible = false;
  OverlayEntry? entry;

  // Listener for stylus
  bool isPenTouched = false;

  /// Hide Overlay Widget
  void hideOverlay() {
    entry?.remove();
    entry = null;
    isOverlayVisible = false;
  }

  /// get Last closed page of workbook
  void _loadLastClosedPage() async {
    final pagePrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _lastClosedPage = pagePrefs.getInt('${widget.workbookName}') ?? 1;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pdfViewerController = PdfViewerController();
    String workbookName = '${widget.workbookName}';
    _loadLastClosedPage();
    print("======== Loaded workbook name = ${workbookName} ==========");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Drawing Provider
    var p = context.read<DrawingProvider>();

    /// set _lastClosedPage
    void countLastClosedPage() async {
      final pagePrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      setState(() {
        pagePrefs.setInt('${widget.workbookName}', _lastClosedPage);
        _lastClosedPage = (pagePrefs.getInt('${widget.workbookName}') ?? 1);
      });
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: buildPenFuncWidgets(p, hideOverlay, context),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: SizedBox(
        child: InteractiveViewer(
          panEnabled: _memoMode ? false : true,
          scaleEnabled: _memoMode ? false : true,
          maxScale: 3,
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              IgnorePointer(
                ignoring: true,
                child: SfPdfViewer.network(
                  widget.downloadedURL,
                  controller: _pdfViewerController,
                  key: _pdfViewerKey,
                  pageLayoutMode: PdfPageLayoutMode.single,
                  enableDoubleTapZooming: false,
                  // Save the last closed page number
                  onPageChanged: (details) {
                    _lastClosedPage = details.newPageNumber;
                    countLastClosedPage();
                  },
                  onDocumentLoaded: (details) {
                    _pdfViewerController.jumpToPage(1);
                  },
                  canShowScrollHead: false,
                ),
              ),

              //  PDF view under drawing layer
              ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: 30,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
              width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: WorkbookDrawingPage());
              },)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> WorkbookDrawingPage.dart

```
class _WorkbookDrawingPageState extends State<WorkbookDrawingPage> {

  // OverlayEntry widget key
  GlobalKey _viewKey = GlobalKey();

  // pen size control widget Entry
  bool isOverlayVisible = false;
  OverlayEntry? entry;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var p = Provider.of<DrawingProvider>(context);
    void hideOverlay() {
      entry?.remove();
      entry = null;
      isOverlayVisible = false;
    }

    return CustomPaint(
      painter: DrawingPainter(p.lines),
      child: Listener(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        // Draw lines when stylus hit the screen
        onPointerDown: (s) {
          if (s.kind == PointerDeviceKind.stylus) {
            p.penMode ? p.penDrawStart(s.localPosition) : null;
            p.highlighterMode
                ? p.highlighterDrawStart(s.localPosition)
                : null;
            p.eraseMode ? p.erase(s.localPosition) : null;

            /// Stylus with button pressed touched the Screen
          } else if (s.kind == PointerDeviceKind.stylus ||
              s.buttons == kPrimaryStylusButton) {
            p.changeEraseModeButtonClicked = true;
          }
        },
        onPointerMove: (s) {
          if (s.kind == PointerDeviceKind.stylus) {
            p.penMode ? p.penDrawing(s.localPosition) : null;
            p.highlighterMode ? p.highlighterDrawing(s.localPosition) : null;
            p.eraseMode ? p.erase(s.localPosition) : null;
          } else if (s.kind == PointerDeviceKind.stylus ||
              s.buttons == kPrimaryStylusButton) {
            p.changeEraseModeButtonClicked = true;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because of the abscent of the constraint and I added the constraint to `Container` Widget with `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*1,` and error fixed.

`double.infinity` don't give the constraint

However, the drawn lines are duplicated.

```
return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*1,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*1,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: DrawingPainter(p.lines),
        child: Listener(
...
```